# Converting a difference of 2 24-hr times into time

Tags: time

Forgive me for my ignorance if its too easy and if its not the right place to post. I have 2 24 hours times strings as 1544 and 1458. Their difference should be 46 minutes but when I subtract them it yields 86 minutes as follows.

```
 1544 
-1458
-------
   86
```

Can someone tell me how can I find a time difference of 2 24-hr times?

Comment: What programming language are you working with?

Answer (score 3):

Hour doesn't have 100 minutes, but unfortunately only 60. You need to do this:

```
 15*60+44
-14*60+58
---------
       46
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in C#, you can try to parse them to DateTime using

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.ParseExact("1544","HHmm",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime date2 = DateTime.ParseExact("1458","HHmm",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

and then subtract them:

```
TimeSpan diff = date1 - date2
```